# Rails routing optional prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have events which are accessible at `/events/eventname` I would also like the same events to be available at `/events/PREFIX-eventname`

I'm currently using the default:

`resources :events` in routes.rb

Initially idea was to add another routing statement

`get "/events/prefix-:id" => "events#show"`

Will adding an additional rule conflict with the resource statement? What's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right! Just add another routing statement:

```
resources :events
get "/events/prefix-:id" => "events#show"
```

This will create two routes to `#show` action.